# Cannot resolve symbol 'ProtectionLevel' for MessageHeaderAttribute in .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

In .net framework we can specify the protection level for a class used in WCF as such:

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(ProtectionLevel=ProtectionLevel.None)]
public ISomeInterface SomeObject;
```

However, in .net core, there does not seem to be an option to specify the protection level for a MessageHeaderAttribute.  This is a problem as the WCF service our organisation needs to submit information to requires that ProtectionLevel to be set to None for the object.

Can this be achieved in .net core?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it somehow?